# Relay email for some addresses, forward for others with Postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp, mail-forwarding

I administer a domain (let's say `example.com`) for a client who uses an Exchange server at an external service provider for email. So I made the MX record point to the Exchange server, let's say `mail.provider.com`. Now I want email to a single address `me@example.com` forwarded to my own email account `me@me.com`. Unfortunately, the service provider told me that they're not able to do this for some reason.

Since I have control over the MX record, my idea is to make it point to my own server running Postfix and

- forward email to `me@example.com` to `me@me.com`
- relay all other addresses to `mail.provider.com`

The solution I came up with is to add the domain to `relay_domains` and set up a Postfix transport map

```
relay_domains = example.com
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

that contains

```
me@example.com    virtual:
example.com       :[mail.provider.com]
.example.com      :[mail.provider.com]
```

Then add an entry to the virtual alias map

```
me@example.com    me@me.com
```

I think this should work but it looks a bit ugly. Would this work at all? Is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead putting me@example.com in transport_maps, you can skip that step and use `virtual_alias_maps` directly.

```
# transport maps
example.com       :[mail.provider.com]
.example.com      :[mail.provider.com]

# virtual alias maps
me@example.com    me@me.com
```

Virtual alias maps is special mapping in postfix that overrides email aliasing regardless their domain class. You can use it for *relay_domains*, *local_domains*, or *virtual_mailbox_domains*.

<sub>Beside technical point, I would also point out that *your client will aware* that your server sit in front of their real server. They may think that you are snooping their conversation. You should think the some implications from this method.</sub>

Comment: I'm looking for something similar as in my case email are being forwarded by using the original emails of a sender. I want to forward all email to my gmail but by using server address. Will your solution work for me?