# per-user transport with postfixadmin

Tags: g-suite, postfix

We have a traditional postfix/dovecot/postfixadmin setup for mail delivery and imap access.
We would like to use a mixed setup with Google Apps in the future, and use their mail service for the major and important accounts (around 10 accounts) and leave the other 200 accounts on the traditional postfixadmin setup.
We tested the setup and this works for sending and receiving external Mails. 
If a traditional user is sending to an Google App User, the mail is transported locally instead of the external transport way.

The MX records are pointing to Googles MX servers, so nothing wrong here.
I read in several other threads about workarounds for "per-user" transport with postfixadmin but nothing worked with our setup so far.

Which would be the best solution for solving this problem?
There is a 3.0 beta of postfixadmin available but the changelog has no news for a "per-user transport" feature. We are currently using version 2.3.5 of postfixadmin.

Transport Settings in postfix:

```
virtual_transport = dovecot
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

content of */etc/postfix/transport*

```
autoreply.hostname.com        vacation
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd imagine you'll just have to do it by hand for the moment, 90% of it will probably be MySQL tables that postfixadmin doesn't touch anyhow.

Comment: THanks for your answer Nick. What exactly do you mean by "do it by hand"? Use postfix rules bypassing postfixadmin? If so, how to do that in the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: No, basically you'd hop into MySQL, and type `INSERT INTO transport  (fieldname1, fieldname2) values ('email@domain', 'transport:nexthop');` I don't know exactly what values or fields are used, but you should have a transport table in your postfix DB.

Comment: Thanks @NickW - this version of postfixadmin has no transport table. It has a transport field in the domain table and afaik the allowed values are (virtual, relay, local). None of these settings solves my problem.

Comment: How is transport set up for you at the moment? In `main.cf` do you have a `transport_maps` setting?

Comment: Yes, please see the initial posting for the contents of main.cf regarding transport_maps - Thanks!

Comment: Does the question/answer [Relay email for some addresses, forward for others with Postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/656067/relay-email-for-some-addresses-forward-for-others-with-postfix) help you?

Comment: Ah, then all you'll need to do is add in the email address you want to send via the transport, then the transport:nexthop (if it's somewhere non standard), then `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` ..

Comment: Thanks very much @NickW - This worked finally! Would you like to post a real answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow for custom, per-user transport, postfix has this functionality built in. To set it up based on your transport table `hash:/etc/postfix/transport` you will just need to add a line into that file for each email user who needs a custom transport. The additions need to be in the format `email  transport:nexthop`.

`user1@example.org  smtp:mail.serv.er`

This would send all of user1's outgoing mail via smtp through mail.server.er

`user2@example.org  smtp:[12.13.14.15]`

This will send all of user2's email though `12.13.14.15` (the `[]` around the address means no DNS lookup).

When you have completed the addition of the files, you will then need to run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport` which will make postfix rebuild its DB from the text file, and reload itself.